# DoCmd.Open Report Where Clause Syntax Issues With Multiple Criteria And Strings

Tags: vba, ms-access, where-clause

New Member Here - Happy to Be With You!

I'm Hoping you can help me with what seems to me to be a syntax issue. I have a report with multiple subreports, all of which are based upon queries. The queries have criteria to prompt the user to [Enter SampleID]. When I run the report, it works correctly but is cumbersome because I am prompted for each criteria individually so I wanted to create a form with a button and an input field for the user to enter a SampleID. Then the code would pull that SampleID and use it to "answer" the criteria prompts. Clearly, what I have done so far is incorrect as I receive a run time error 13 type mismatch...I tried to find guidance as to how to proper syntax for strings, but those edits don't seem to work :(

Here's the start of the current code for your review and insights - it continues on but the syntax is the same throughout. Note that SampleID is a short text string.

DoCmd.OpenReport "DEV_GenRpt_Comp_Info", , , "Samples.SampleID=" & Me.SampleID And "ReportDemos_TestOrderAndSampleReportInfo.Samples.SampleID=" & Me.SampleID And "200_8_Query.SampleID=" & Me.SampleID And "300_Query.SampleID=" & Me.SampleID

Most appreciated!

Comment: As you using a form and textbox to enter `SampleID` then pass this `SampleID` to all queries directly. Then you can simply open the report without `Where Caluse`. So, data will be filtered from query. In criteria field of the queries use this line `Forms![YourFormName]![SampleID]` Put same line to all queries using to report and sub reports.

Comment: @Harun24HR Thanks! I will try this and let you know!